# How to access contents of a dictionary with String as key and Arrays of Any as values?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm new to Swift and to programming in general. I have declared following `dictionary`:

```
let fruits: [String:[[Any]]]  = [
    "Apple": [
        ["Gravenstein",122,100],
        ["Ginger Gold", 119, 130],
        ["Jazz", 150, 190]

    ],

    "Grapes": [
        ["Cabernet Sauvignon",120,100],
        ["Merlot", 150, 130],
        ["Tempranillo", 130, 190]

    ]
]
```

I want to program a function now that based on 2 variables, say, `var selectedFruit = "Apple"` and `var selectedVariety = "Ginger Gold"`. Based on these 2 variables, I should be able to get the first number (122) and add it to the second number (100). I've tried map and flatmap to no success. Any help ?

Comment: show us what have you tried so far please.

Comment: I did print(fruits.map {$0.key == selectedFruit}) which returns an array [true, false], but here I get stuck....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will get your there:

```
let selectedFruit = "Apple"
let selectedVariety = "Ginger Gold"

if let arrays = fruits[selectedFruit] {
    for array in arrays {
        if let first = array.first as? String, first == selectedVariety {
            if let num1 = array[1] as? Int, let num2 = array[2] as? Int {
                print(num1 + num2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you've almost certainly chosen the wrong structure for your data.  If you find yourself using `Any`, there's a better solution.

The easiest thing to do would be to have nested dictionaries with your fruits and varieties being the keys.

```
let fruits: [String: [String: [Int]]]  = [
    "Apple": [
         "Gravenstein": [122, 100],
         "Ginger Gold": [119, 130],
         "Jazz": [150, 190]
    ],

    "Grapes": [
        "Cabernet Sauvignon": [120, 100],
        "Merlot": [150, 130],
        "Tempranillo": [130, 190]
    ]
]

if let values = fruits[selectedFruit]?[selectedVariety] {
    print(values[0] + values[1])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the new structure is a dictionary with a String as key and an array of dictionaries as values. I get that. What is the purpose of the "?" between [selectedFruit] and [selectedVariety] ?

Comment: The new structure is a dictionary with String as a key and a value that is a dictionary with a String as a key and an array of Ints as its value.  Dictionary lookups always return an Optional result because the key might not exist.  You have to unwrap the result to use it.  The `?` in this case is known as *optional chaining* and unwraps the first dictionary lookup if it isn't `nil` so that the second dictionary lookup can proceed.  If either lookup returns `nil`, the result of the *optional chain* will be `nil`, and the `if let` will not happen.  In any case, this is completely safe.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly I would change the way the dictionary is structured slightly. Instead of having an array of arrays, change it to have an array of dictionaries. So something like the following:

```
let fruits: [String:[String: [Int]]]  = [
    "Apple": [
        "Gravenstein": [122,100],
        "Ginger Gold": [119, 130],
        "Jazz": [150, 190]

    ],

    "Grapes": [
        "Cabernet Sauvignon": [120,100],
        "Merlot": [150, 130],
        "Tempranillo": [130, 190]

    ]
]
```

Once you have done that you can simply write a method like this:

```
func getTotalValue(fruitName: String, varietyName: String) -> Int? {

    guard let varieties = fruits[fruitName] else { return nil }
    guard let values = varieties[varietyName] else { return nil }

    return values.reduce(0, +)
}
```

And use it like so:

```
getTotalValue(fruitName: "Apple", varietyName: "Gravenstein")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function to find your fruits. I have added comments as well, so you might can modify the container for easier search.

```
  // it is enough to say your container is [String: Any]
    let fruits: [String: Any]  = [
        "Apple": [
            ["Gravenstein",122,100],
            ["Ginger Gold", 119, 130],
            ["Jazz", 150, 190]

        ],


    "Grapes": [
        ["Cabernet Sauvignon",120,100],
        ["Merlot", 150, 130],
        ["Tempranillo", 130, 190]

    ]
]

func findFruits(name: String, type: String) -> (Int, Int)? {
    // Declare nil tuple
    var searchedFruitValues: (Int, Int)?
    // First lets see if we have the fruit in the container
    if let fruit = fruits[name] as? [[Any]]{
        // Iterate through every element
        fruit.forEach({ (element) in
            // If the first element is equal to the searched type, check the numbers
            if type == (element.first as? String) {
                // If they are integers, lets associate the value to searchedFruitValues
                if let first = element[1] as? Int, let second = element[2] as? Int {
                    searchedFruitValues = (first, second)
                }
            }  
        })
    }
    // Return nil or the found values
    return searchedFruitValues
}

let searched = findFruits(name: "Apple", type: "Jazz")
print(searched ?? "not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
struct Fruit {
    var name : String
    var variety : [Variety]
}

struct Variety {
    var name : String
    var numbers : [Int]

    func getNumbers() -> Int {
        var result = 0
        for value in self.numbers {
            result += value
        }
        return result
    }
}

//example data
let apples = [
    Variety(name: "Gravenstein", numbers: [122, 100]),
    Variety(name: "Ginger Gold", numbers: [119, 130])
]

let grapes = [
    Variety(name: "Cabernet Sauvignon", numbers: [120,100]),
    Variety(name: "Merlot", numbers: [150, 130])
]


let fruits = [
    Fruit(name: "Apple", variety: apples),
    Fruit(name: "Garpes", variety: grapes)
]

//the actual call for the Variety numbers 
   if let goldenGinger = fruits.first(where: { $0.name == "Apple"})?.variety.first(where: { $0.name == "Ginger Gold"}) {
        print(goldenGinger.getNumbers())
    }
```